# Are density matrices symmetric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, trace

The context is that I want to simplify an expression like

$$
\mathrm{Trace}[\rho_1 \rho_2 \rho_3] + \mathrm{Trace}[\rho_2 \rho_1 \rho_3]
$$
(Note that the second term is not a cyclic permutation of the first one)

If the density matrices happen to be symmetric then the above expression will simplify to just 
$$
2 \mathrm{Trace}[\rho_1 \rho_2 \rho_3]
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.

Comment: Density matrices are hermitian. How do you write an example density matrix for a pure state with two components?

Comment: Do a unitary transformation on a diagonal non-degenerate matrix. What do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: density matrices are Hermitian ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix)), they may or may not be real symmetric (depending, among other things, on the basis you use).

Regarding your motivation: symmetric (or Hermitian) matrices do not necessarily commute, therefore even if the density matrices you care about are symmetric, you might not be able to simplify the sum as you state. For the matrices to commute you would need them to be simultaneously diagonalizable, i.e., there should be a basis where both (or all) are diagonal.

Comment: For symmetric matrices, did you utilize the cyclicity of the trace to bring $\rho_2$ to the central position?

Comment: Matrices don't commute but as I want to find the trace of three matrices, I can use the properties of traces.